# How to create properties from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I have a dictionary with some basic settings such as:

```
config = {'version': 1.0,
          'name': 'test'
          }
```

Using this config, I'd like to setup a class like so:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._version = config['version']
        self._name = config['name']

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._version
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

Is there a way to create these properties (with the nice automatic getter+setter) without having to explicitly write out all the functions?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need properties as opposed to simple instance attributes? If not you could do self.__dict__.update(config).

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if you make your class inherit from `dict`

```
class PropDict(dict):
    __getattr__= dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__
```

Comment: This is a really interesting and clever solution to this problem... first time I've seen it. I'm undecided whether I love it or think it might be slightly too magical for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple solution without any bells and whistles, I was thinking along the same lines as @PaulPanzer:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.__dict__.update(config)

    # If you want to keep other attributes from getting set
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError(key)
        self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `__getattr__` method:

```
config = {'version': 1.0,
      'name': 'test'
      }
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self._version = config['version']
      self._name = config['name']
   def __getattr__(self, name):
      data = [b for a, b in self.__dict__.items() if a[1:] == name]
      if not data:
          raise AttributeError('{} not found'.format(name))
      return data[0]
```

Output:

```
f = Foo()
print(f.name)
```

Output:

```
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Some adds

```
config = {'version': 1.0,
          'name': 'test',
          'date': "18/12/2018"
          }


class Config:
   def __init__(self, config):
      'creates the object'
      self.__dict__.update(config)

   def add(self, k, v):
      'adds a key with a value'
      self.__dict__[k] = v

   def list(self):
      'shows all the keys'
      for k in self.__dict__.keys():
         print(k)

>>> f = Config(config)
>>> f.list()
version
name
date
>>>
```